# [ERROR] fatal: cannot exec 'fetch-pack': Argument list too long

Tags: ros, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody, I'm a ROS newbie and I'm trying to build it since a few days ago.
First I tried in a VM with CrunchBang #! but it had a lot of errors.
Now I'm trying in my native OS (Snow Leopard), and I'm having a bunch of errors trying to build even the bare bones distribution.

**fatal: cannot exec 'fetch-pack': Argument list too long**

I understand that's an error of **git**, but I mean I'm having 3 pages of errors so I can't build ROS as it should be.

Hope somebody can help me a bit to find a solution.
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70825/%5Berror%5D-fatal:-cannot-exec-%27fetch-pack%27:-argument-list-too-long/) by [LuisGIII](https://answers.ros.org/users/5716/luisgiii/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-08-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have struck upon a workaround. The error you are experiencing occurs because of the way that Git handles smart HTTP (read `http://code.google.com/r/renyanemma-gitcore/source/detail?r=078b895fefdca94995862a4cc8644198b00a89bf` for a good explanation).

This issue exists only when Git uses Smart HTTP, which is the default choice that `rosinstall_generator` makes for you when it generates a `.rosinstall` file. By changing:

`uri: https://github.com/ros-gbp/ros_comm-release.git`

```
                                        to
```

`uri: git@github.com:ros-gbp/ros_comm-release.git`

for each affected item in your `.rosinstall` file, Git will use SSH to clone the source repositories instead, which apparently does not create problems for your terminal's argument buffer.

Simply replace-all `https://github.com/` to `git@github.com:` in your favorite text editor (sed included), and you should be all set.

---

Originally posted by [acarrillo](https://answers.ros.org/users/7641/acarrillo/) with karma: 16 on 2013-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0